# Realistic Render In Cycles

Tags: modeling, rendering

I've set up some nodes in the shading editor, I have made a control, I added a texture node to give it some noise, but the overall render doesn't give it a realistic feeling, it lacking that sense of a real object. What more would I need to add to my scene, or nodes, or render?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Universal tips: Add more geometry - the edges are very sharp and cannot be shaded properly. Add surface imperfections - scratches, fingerprints textures. And add environment - just a plane behind and underneath to cast shadow onto. Good luck :).

Comment: Thanks for your tip Jachym!